# How to filter a queryset for the highest value in one field grouped by each value in another field?

Tags: django, aggregate, django-queryset

If I have a model like this

```
from django.db import models

class Thing(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique = True, null=False)
    version = models.IntegerField(null = False)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
```

and I have a bunch of entries like

```
Thing.objects.create(name = "foo1", version = 1, type = "A")
Thing.objects.create(name = "foo2", version = 2, type = "A")
Thing.objects.create(name = "bar1", version = 1, type = "B")
Thing.objects.create(name = "bar2", version = 2, type = "B")
Thing.objects.create(name = "bar3", version = 3, type = "B")
```

How do I write a single Django query that will give me one entry for each of type `type` with the highest `version`? So, this result:

```
Queryset< Thing(name = "foo2", version = 2, type = "A"), 
Thing(name = "bar3", version = 3, type = "B") >
```

I was looking at the docs here; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/

And its easy to do something like this;

```
Thing.objects.aggregate(Max('version'))
```

But this would only give me `Thing(name = "bar3", version = 3, type = "B")`

Answer (score 0):

This groups by `type` and filters by max `version`:

```
Things.objects.values('type').annotate(max_version=Max('version'))
```